# Error when Adding Google GMS Service to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've been trying to add the GMS services to my android studio project and I always get this error when trying to sync the project.

```
Gradle 'SchoolingSolution' project refresh failed
Error:Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
```

Part of my stack trace from my log is also below

```
.project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:339)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:230)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo
```

Answer (score -1):

you should try the following:

1) Close your Android Studio

2) go to android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib

3) Delete (or better move them somewhere to have a backup) all gradle-*-1.8 files

4) Start Android Studio again and rebuild/refresh.

It should work.

Note: Try the new compile setting Settings -> Compiler -> Gradle and activate the third in-process build for a speed up. Depending on your project setting you might want to select the first one as well.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work I keep getting this excepting `Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.LogSetup.initLoggers(LogSetup.java:54) at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.<clinit>(BuildMain.java:57)`

Comment: My gradle version is 2.5, so I moved all 2.5 files it didn't work, tried moving out all the gradle files too, still didn't work